# How can I login to all parts of my website using all login forms?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, single-sign-on

I have 3 different login forms on my website and each of them use different software. Example: phpfox, Wordpress, etc.

They are all connected to 1 central database so the same user can login to all 3 forms. All 3 pieces of software are, however, using different tables inside that database.

The problem is that they have to sign into each form separately and it would be nice if they could just login to 1 and then be logged into all 3 pieces of software without having to type in their information again.

Can I just add 2 "hidden" forms to each form so that they will all submit when a user logs in to any one of the forms? What would be the easiest way to accomplish this task?

-Thanks!

Comment: Or... Just make a function that mimics/calls the login functionality of the three and makes each "logged in" at once.

Comment: ... and another logout function that does the opposite... (while redirecting each app's login/logout functionality back to the single setup.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but hidden forms are probably not the answer, since, outside of AJAX, you cannot submit more than one form at a time and you will definitely require some server-side data massaging anyways, so you might as well take care of all data preparation there.

Just collect the regular inputs on the client side and look into what is required to log into each of the systems you want on the server side. There might even be an API for some.

Check out the answer to this question on authenticating to WordPress:
[Wordpress Authenticate Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102134/wordpress-authenticate-filter)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have the pieces of the user's information stored in separate cookies, including the password's HASHED value.

I am only familiar with PHP, but I am certain the other softwares can call a cookie stored by any of the others.

You should rely on sessions to authenticate the user's cookie as well.

For example in PHP, if you can set `$_COOKIE['id']` and `$_COOKIE['hashpass']`, you could call upon the other softwares to validate the cookies stored in the user's browser and initiate a session.

Hopefully you are storing the passwords' values as HASHES as well, so checking the HASH against a HASH would only cause a very minor security problem, which is why you should [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) all of your password hashes.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.