# WORDPRESS: I have just created an extra column with phpMyadmin on my wp_user row, I now need each user to update that column when logged in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

WORDPRESS: I have just created an extra column with phpMyadmin on my wp_user row (foo), I now need each user to update their column when logged in. I have successfully called the value for each user by:

```
            <?php

        $wpdb->hide_errors(); auth_redirect_login(); nocache_headers();
                    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
                        // Not logged in.
                    } else {
                        echo '<input>' . $current_user->foo . '/>';


                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Work to improve format of your question. Good and proper format of a question shows that you really need a solution for this

Comment: Sometimes its better to say you don't know something (eg wordpress or english in this case) than blame others for your lack of grammar and understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please explain why you did alter the WordPress table ?

It is such a bad practice. I highly doubt your column would persist if WP has to update somewhere in time.

There is a table called WP_Usermeta that fits your needs.

You can access and update your value with:

update_usermeta($userId,'foo',"1");

$foo = get_usermeta($userId,'foo');

**Now**, for your main issue, you can overload the wp_authenticate function OR, use a filter like "Authenticate" (taken from [mjangda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806638/380392)).

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'check_login', 10, 3 );

function check_login( $user, $username, $password ) {

    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $username ); 

    if( /* check to see if user is allowed */ ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: EXPLANATION: "Simply put, it was an oversight on the update requirements, now that you have opened my eyes I gues I will do away with those fields." Tell you what Pier-Luc? I'm proud of you! not only did you take your time to read my post, but you did answer me successfully, for that I'm gna VOTE.